# Java regex pattern for a REST filter/search param?

Tags: java, regex

I have a filter param in my REST API that can look like this:

```
owner='bob'                            // owner is bob
owner!'bob'                            // owner is not bob
owner.town='bel*'                      // owner's town starts with bel
owner.town='*bel*'                     // owner's town contains bel
owner.car='{ some json blob here}'     // owner's car equals some json blob
owner.car~                             // owner has a property named car
```

So I want to capture:

- A required String key
- The can contain letters, numbers, underscores, dots, hyphens or colons
- A required operator: +|!|~
- An optional value, that can begin and/or end with an optional asterisk
- If the optional value is present, it must be surrounded by single quotes

I have started with the following, buts it's not returning what I'd expect:

```
String filter = "owner='bob'";
Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(=|!|~)(*?)(\\w+?)(*?)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filter);

// Results
matcher.group(1)   // "owner"
matcher.group(2)   // "="
matcher.group(3)   // "\"
matcher.group(4)   // ""
matcher.group(5)   // "bob"
matcher.group(6)   // ""
matcher.group(7)   // "\"
```

Problems I'm having:

- I don't think `(*?)` is correctly capturing zero or one asterisks
- Passing "owner~" results in a failure when invoking `matcher.group(anything)`

I'm pretty sure there are other problems with the regex I havn't found yet...

Comment: Are you familiar with regex testing sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com) or [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)? They should help you figure out these types of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following regex :

```
^([\w.:-]+)([=!~])('.*')?$
```

It is composed of three consecutive groups defined as follows :

- a first group matches the key, which is a non-empty sequence of letters, numbers, underscores, dots, hyphens or colons.
- a second group matches the operator, which is one of "=", "!" or "~"
- a third optional group matches the rest, which would be the property value when the operator isn't "~"

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/XTMRCY/6).

Note that if the mention that the value can start or end with a `*` is supposed to imply that it can't contain `*` in other places you will want to change the third group into `('\*?[^*]*\*?')`.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, forgot to say in my post that key can contain letters, numbers, underscores, dots, hyphens or colons, updated my question now

Comment: @Rory I've edited my answer to take those into account. It's just a matter of listing them into the character class (knowing that `\w` includes letters, numbers and underscore) and making sure you put the `-` first or last so it's not interpreted as a range

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, just a quick semi-related question for you :-) What's the difference between your regex for the ley and this one: ```"^(?!\\s*$)[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\. :]+$"``` - are they basically the same?

Comment: @Rory in your regex `[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\. :]+` matches any letter, number, underscore, dash, dot, space or colon one or more time. That part can be simplified into `[\w .:-]+` (`\w` contains letters, numbers and underscore, the dot doesn't need to be escaped inside a character class, and neither does the `-` if it's first or last). Using `^...$` makes sure you're matching the whole string or nothing, and `(?!\\s*$)` makes sure the whole string you're matching isn't just spaces.

Comment: Great thanks @Aaron, one more question, is it possible to have the optional asterisks at the start and end of the value in separate capture groups? So I could assign them to `suffix` and `prefix` variables easily?

Comment: Sure, see the suggested `('\*?[^*]*\*?')` alternative? That's a quote, followed by a single optional asterisk, followed by any number of non-asterisk characters, followed by an optional asterisk, followed by the closing quote. Just put the two asterisks in their own capturing group, and you will likely prefer to make the group itself optional rather than the character : `(\*)?` (nb : in Java you'll need to double every ``\`` I'm writing)

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, I've tried ending the pattern with this ```(\\*)?('.*')?(\\*)?```, but it's capturung ```*bob*``` in capture group 4, instead of ```*``` in capture group 3, ```bob``` in capture group 4, and ```*``` in capture group 5? (Note that it's ok for the value to contain asterisks as well, not just start and end with them)

Comment: @Rory looking at your samples the * should be inside the '...' rather than outside, so more like `'(\\*)?(.*)(\\*)?'` maybe?

Comment: `([\w.:-]+)([=!~])(?:'(\*?)([^']+?)(\*?)')?` should work

Comment: Thanks @Aaron (and anubhava)

Comment: anubhava, it's nearly perfect but doesn't match this: owner.town=bel*

Comment: Looks like you'd need to make the quotes optional for that case

Comment: Thanks, I've tried changing ```'``` to ```'?``` but doesn't seem to work, is there something I'm missing here? https://regex101.com/r/XTMRCY/8

Comment: Try `^([\w.:-]+)([=!~])'?(\*?)([^']+?)(\*?)'?$` You needed anchors in order for your lazy quantifier not to become too lazy

Comment: `^([\w.:-]+)([=!~])'?(\*?)([^']*?)(\*?)'?$` in order for `key~`  to still match (all tokens after the operator made optional)

Comment: Perfect, thanks again or all your help @Aaron, it really is appreciated! :-)

Comment: Sorry, one last thing, any ideas why the matcher would working in regex101, but not in Java? ```private final static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^([\\w.:-]+)([=!])'?(\\*?)([^']+?)(\\*?)'?$"); final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher("owner='bob'"); matcher.group(1); // returns no match found?``` Note, I no longer want owner~ to match, so using your first example

Comment: @Rory you need to call `matcher.matches()` (or `.find()`, but `.matches()` seems more relevant in your case) before you can call `matcher.group`